# Xamarin VS2015 - Project is not up to date ... is modified after output

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have been unable to build Xamarin in VS2015 projects owing to variations of the following.

Even generating a new project with the hello world template (as shown here) fails to build.

MSBuild and Xamarin is set to diagnostic, and further on other errors are generated

I cannot build either in the VS emulator, nor on a Samsung Galaxy S5

Fast deployment is turned off.

Under Build order from a fresh project...

```
1>Project 'deletethis' is not up to date. Missing output file 'C:\Dropbox\Xamarin ProjectsInManual 2016\deletethis\deletethis\bin\Debug\deletethis.dll'.
```

from another build

```
1>Project 'deletethis' is not up to date. Input file 'C:\Dropbox\Xamarin ProjectsInManual 2016\deletethis\deletethis\deletethis.csproj' is modified after output file 'C:\Dropbox\Xamarin ProjectsInManual 2016\deletethis\deletethis\bin\Debug\deletethis.pdb'.
```

The file names change, but the message is the same. So one time it will be deletethis.pdb another deletethis.dll' etc.

Happens with debug and Release

Answer (score 0):

Could you try moving your solution from Dropbox folder to a normal folder. Just a wild guess .....

If you have recently updated xamarin you may want to revert to an older version

Answer (score 0):

This weird problem may have a weird [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38581cce-9ab4-4741-a4e1-3e2abb0ab935#answers): run Visual Studio as administrator.